# `webshot` in R throws "I'm `fs` modules PHANTOM ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor"

Tags: r, phantomjs

Trying to use various tools in R that produce images using the `webshot` package. In all cases I get "PHANTOM ERROR" like the one described below:

MWE with trace below, followed by my system information:

```
> library(webshot)

> URL <- "http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/"
 
> webshot(URL, delay = 0.5)

I'm `fs` modules
PHANTOM ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('fs').pathJoin(phantom.casperPath, 'modules', 'clientutils.js')')
TRACE:
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 1309 (in function injectClientUtils)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 713 (in function evaluate)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 1008 (in function getCurrentUrl)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 1590 (in function runStep)
 -> phantomjs://platform/casper.js: 406 (in function checkStep)
Error in webshot(URL, delay = 0.5) : webshot.js returned failure value: 1

> traceback()
2: stop("webshot.js returned failure value: ", res)
1: webshot(URL, delay = 0.5)
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] webshot_0.5.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ps_1.6.0        digest_0.6.28   R6_2.5.1        jsonlite_1.7.2 
 [5] magrittr_2.0.1  evaluate_0.14   rlang_0.4.11    renv_0.14.0    
 [9] callr_3.7.0     rmarkdown_2.11  tools_4.1.1     xfun_0.26      
[13] yaml_2.2.1      fastmap_1.1.0   compiler_4.1.1  processx_3.5.2 
[17] htmltools_0.5.2 knitr_1.35     

> Sys.info()     
                                                                                      sysname                                                                                          
 "Darwin"                                                                                            release                                                                                           "20.6.0"                                                                                            
version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:21 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_X86_64" 
  ...

> system(paste(webshot:::find_phantom(), "--version"))
2.1.1
```

I tried:

- restarting R
- reinstalling phantomJS
- installing an older version of phantomJS (not sure that took though)
- updating xcode
- updating xQuartz
- reinstalling R

Nothing helped. All my colleagues can run this without error.

Comment: To help with debugging, please run the following right after seeing one of the errors, and post the output in your question:  `traceback()`  (to see where the error is coming from), `sessionInfo()` (mainly to see what versions of packages are involved).

Comment: OK, I adjusted this. Does this give you a clue? (Thanks user2554330)

Comment: Everything there looks fine, same as my system which doesn't get the error.  Maybe try `system(paste(webshot:::find_phantom(), "--version"))`?  I get `2.1.1`.  Alternatively, you could try `webshot2` which uses a completely different mechanism; currently it's not on CRAN, so you install with `remotes::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")`.  The function is still called `webshot()`.

Comment: I also get 2.1.1. \\

So actually, installing webshot2 seems to make the code above work, at least it outputs 

```
http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/ screenshot completed
```

So if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it. 

But sadly for me, this does not fix the problem in the context I needed it. (Will add another response), so I'll need to start another post.

Comment: ... 
I actually wanted the code to work with `kableExtra::save_kable`. And that is still yielding the same `PHANTOM ERROR`.  I guess `save_kable` is using the original `webshot` and not `webshot2`.  I'm not sure how to switch that or if it's possible. I'll make another post. Thanks.

Comment: There's an open issue (https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/618) asking for `webshot2` support in `kableExtra`.  It would be a very easy change to switch from `webshot` to `webshot2`, but more work to make the change optional.